# How this equation of the voltage is attained?

Tags: circuit-analysis, kirchhoffs-laws, voltage

I've may been asking the very easy question.
[image]
The each resistor has the same resistance(given by \$r\$).

The textbooks states the following.

\$V_{AB}=r\{i_1+i_2+i_3+(I-i_1)\}\$

How the above equation is attained?

Can anyone tell me some hint(s)? so that I can deduce it in my own.

Comment: Where are nodes A and B in the circuit?

Comment: Sorry.The node1 applies to the node A.

Comment: I doubt your textbook answer is incorrect. You sure this circuit diagram is correct?

Comment: @user533652886 I didn't check, but assuming the currents are correctly labeled then your equation is wrong. It should be \$V_\text{AB}=r\cdot\left[i_1+i_2+2\cdot i_3+\left(I-i_1\right)\right]\$. Just follow around the lower and right edges. It falls out.

Comment: I think the diagram is correct.

Comment: I'll calculate the value of \$V_{AB}\$ using concrete values.

Comment: I got the correct value using @jonk 's equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find voltage between \$A\$ and \$B\$ , traverse from node B to A through any of the paths, and add all the voltage drops along the way. For instance, you can follow this path:
[image]

P.S: Assuming that the circuit and current directions are correct, you will find that the textbook answer is wrong for \$V_{AB}\$.